# InnoDB full-text search (no lucene)

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a problem. I have a managed VPS server running MySQL 5.1.x. I am currently building a new database where I want to store tweets (via search, stream, timeline etc). So I want to use InnoDB database engine because of the row locking! But unfortunately, MySQL 5.1 does not support Full-text search in InnoDB tables.

The problem is that I cannot update my server by myself. So I cannot install MySQL 5.6 (that should support Full-text search) and I cannot install lucene (or solr or whatever).

Are there other options to achieve Full-text search in MySQL or whatever. Or maybe in PostgreSQL (never used that before)

The only other option I have so far is going to an unmanaged VPS but I don't prefer that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) engine but it's not transactional.

The other other possible solution is create another table with engine [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) or ARIA and create a relationship between the new table and the "store tweets" table, so before insert into the 'new table' make sure that 'store tweets' it's not locked.

Comment: That is probably not possible. I don't want to use MyISAM because of the table locking when inserting. There are to many inserts! I had thought about an extra MyISAM table, but then I would still have inserts issues.

Comment: you won't, if you make any query to the InnoDB table first and before to release it, make the insert/update into the MyISAM table, you will keep the integrity because the main table (the Innodb) will be locked and meanwhile you make the changes into the other table.

Comment: Like creating a temp table everytime I run a query with Full-text search?

Comment: no, I was thinking more like trying to lock Innodb, insert into table MyISAM and then release table Innodb, if the Innodb is locked the MyISAM will not execute, you have to try it first to see if it will work